# Extracting text from a binary PE file in python

Tags: python, dll, binary, exe, portable-executable

I am trying to extract strings from a PE files (.exe & .dll) using `pefile` library but for a while I am stuck as this type of data format is new to new, I've read many questions similar to mine but with no success I am able to adapt the code to fit my needs.

I have a following code:

```
# path to random pe file
p = 'dfghdsfhrtkl54165hs.exe'
pe = pefile.PE(p)

# Extract the file's metadata
print('Machine: ', pe.FILE_HEADER.Machine)
print('Number of sections: ', pe.FILE_HEADER.NumberOfSections)
print('Timestamp: ', pe.FILE_HEADER.TimeDateStamp)
print('Entry point: ', pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint)
```

```
# Machine:  332
# Number of sections:  3
# Timestamp:  1441263997
# Entry point:  5432
```

As I understand there are `sections` that contain `.text` which can be used to classify if the file is bening or malignant so I've tried the following:

```
for section in pe.sections:
    if section.Name.decode().strip('\x00') == '.text':
        text_section = section
        break

text_section
```

Which returns

```
<Structure: [IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER] 0x1B0 0x0 
Name: .text 0x1B8 0x8 
Misc: 0xF53C 0x1B8 0x8 
Misc_PhysicalAddress: 0xF53C 0x1B8 0x8 
Misc_VirtualSize: 0xF53C 0x1BC 0xC 
VirtualAddress: 0x1000 0x1C0 0x10 
SizeOfRawData: 0x10000 0x1C4 0x14 
PointerToRawData: 0x1000 0x1C8 0x18 
PointerToRelocations: 0x0 0x1CC 0x1C 
PointerToLinenumbers: 0x0 0x1D0 0x20 
NumberOfRelocations: 0x0 0x1D2 0x22 
NumberOfLinenumbers: 0x0 0x1D4 0x24 
Characteristics: 0x60000020>
```

But I am unsure how to proceed extracting printable strings from this or if this is even the right way.

I've read the following answers:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027990/how-can-i-get-text-section-from-pe-file-using-pefile)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804582/extract-strings-from-a-binary-file-in-python)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139889/extracting-text-section-only-from-a-pe-file)

My end goal is to extract text from PE files that I can use in my ML model as features.